# Exporting a Pattern to Image in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I am designing a website and in the background I am using a pattern that is done by somebody else.

Now while slicing, is there anyway to find and select the exact dimensions of the pattern that the other designer has used to create that pattern instead of guessing it?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ensure you have **Tool Tips on in the preferences**.

[image]

In the pattern library popup, when you click on a pattern, the tooltip should tell you what dimension it is. Start a new document with this dimension, and fill using the pattern. You should end up with a non-repeated image of the original pattern size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know exact dimensions of that pattern, there is one way - ask the other designer, which created that pattern ). Photoshop store pattern parameters in psd only if pattern applying to layer with layer effects. In another case we can only guessing it size.

[image]

I think, that you must think about optimizating pattern size (that you have done) instead of how pattern was done. Good luck!