# How big is my single pattern in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tiles

I pulled a repeating pattern from someone else's PSD. Is there a way to figure out the size of the original pattern? I need to create an image with only one tile.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question was first posted in a similar [thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/234/exporting-a-pattern-to-image-in-photoshop) in regards to exporting patterns by Jin.

[image]

> In the pattern library popup, when you click on a pattern, the tooltip
>   should tell you what dimension it is. Start a new document with this
>   dimension, and fill using the pattern. You should end up with a
>   non-repeated image of the original pattern size.

Comment: Just a note: You **must** have tool tips on in the preferences to see the tile size pop up.

Answer (score -1):

Check "Show Tooltips" & uncheck "Use Rich Tooltips"

[image]

Comment: How does that answer the question?